# How to convert from dataframe to RDD and back with a case class

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out how I can convert a dataframe to a RDD (so I can do pair operations) and back again.  Currently when I do this I get an exception for "GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to SaltedUser"

I start off with a case class

```
case class SaltedUser(salt: Long, userId: Long)
```

Next I create a dataframe

```
scala> Seq((1, SaltedUser(1, 1)), (2, SaltedUser(2, 2)), (3, SaltedUser(3, 3))).toDF("key", "SaltedUser").show
+---+----------+
|key|SaltedUser|
+---+----------+
|  1|    [1, 1]|
|  2|    [2, 2]|
|  3|    [3, 3]|
+---+----------+
```

Now if i was to convert this to a RDD (e.g. because i want to do a reduceByKey) and convert it back

```
scala> Seq((1, SaltedUser(1, 1)), (2, SaltedUser(2, 2)), (3, SaltedUser(3, 3))).toDF("key", "SaltedUser").rdd.map(r => (r.getInt(0), r.getAs[SaltedUser](1))).toDF.show
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to SaltedUser
```

Perhaps I am going about this the wong way or otherwise there is some custom way to do the casting ?

Comment: Are you sure it happens when converting to df?
seems to me like the problem is in the command r.getAs[SaltedUser](1).
can you confirm or debunk this?

Comment: as per Yaron's link, Seq((1, SaltedUser(1, 1)), (2, SaltedUser(2, 2)), (3, SaltedUser(3, 3))).toDF("key", "SaltedUser").as[keySaltedUser].rdd.map(m => (m.key,m.saltedUser)).toDF("key","SaltedUser").show is working

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @hadooper, just wondering if as[keySaltedUser] is a typo or should i define an new case class called keySaltedUser ?

Comment: should be new case class with field type Int and salteduser